# How to remotely debug graphic application with QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, qt-creator

I develop a cross-platform Qt application. And now I need/want to run it on a remote host with GUI form loading.
I know 2 ways to do that:

- open application on a remote display (may be virtual) with console attached to QtCreator via `ssh`
- run with remote X session, like it done with `ssh -X` or `-Y`.

When I run an application through QtCreator on the remote device it says

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

When I connect to remote host with `ssh -Y` and run my app, it says

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:10.0
Aborted
```

On my local host and on remote host via VNC the application works fine.

`ssh -Y user@host xclock` also works fine - opens it's form on my local display.

Host system is *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64*, target system *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x86 32bit*. Qt version 5.9.1

Please help me to make it work. In worst case I agree to see debug console in and `gdb` attached to QtCreator, but the GUI could still be placed on a remote display.

---

Update:
Here is related question on [form.qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/86047/how-to-make-qtcreator-to-connect-to-a-remote-device-generic-linux-with-x-forwarding-enabled-ssh-x/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and help from QtCreator community I found
The way is simple:

1. Open ssh session to remote host with X forwarding enabled `ssh -X user@host`. And get know the `DISPLAY` variable. For example with `echo $DISPLAY`. It should look like `localhost:10.0`.
2. Set environment variable `DISPLAY` in QtCreator -> *Projects -> YourConfiguration -> Run -> RunEnvironment* to known value from (1).
3. Run and **enjoy** remote debug with GUI on local machine.

Note: closing ssh session will make forwarded display inaccessible and invalid.