# Qt Creator runs application on remote device (raspberry), but the app never shows

Tags: qt, qt-creator, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

I have cross compiled Qt5.12.3 on my Ubuntu machine for raspberry pi 3B+ as the target device. Everything is fine and my application is cross-compiled successfully.

The issues is that after building the app, the app runs but never opens. The qt creator just shows this message: "Starting /home/pi/myApp..." but the app never shows up.

[image: qtcreator snapshot]

It seems the application process is running on the target device. Also I can run the app from my rasp terminal. I think there should be some problem with displaying the app in my Ubuntu remotely.

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the process running on your raspberry to display a window on your Ubuntu computer ?

Comment: @BenjaminT yes :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `DISPLAY` variable in the Run environment.

To know which value you need to set it too, you can do:

```
ssh -X user@host
echo $DISPLAY
```

It should looke like `hostname@1.0`

Comment: Thanks for answering. It gave me localhost@10.0 and I have added to the run env but didn't help :(

Comment: @Mosi Not that it matters for the current problem, but do not `sudo ssh` ssh does not need root privilege.

Comment: @Mosi Apparently you need to keep the ssh session open. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47838027/2667360

Comment: Yeah, it's open but not helping :(